# Im trying to make a 2D array in ruby that basically functions as a excel sheet for tracking inventory

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create an inventory list in ruby that holds objects based on a `name` attribute, e.g.

```
class Item
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I'm trying to make the inventory look like this: (one row per name)

```
[
  [Item.new("foo"), Item.new("foo"), Item.new("foo"), Item.new("foo")],
  [Item.new("bar"), Item.new("bar")],
  [Item.new("baz"), Item.new("baz"), Item.new("baz")]
]
```

I want to be able to `push` and `pop` from each row, and I want to be able to create a new row for a specific name if I haven't reached my capacity of 3. I tried to implement it like how I would vectors in C++, but I think I'm missing some syntax and don't really know where to begin to be honest.

Comment: `list = [[], [], []]` maybe? You would then push, via `list[0].push(obj)` and pop via `obj = list[0].pop` with 0 being the array’s index.

Comment: @Stefan I think the initialization of the array was my problem, I was trying to do `list = Array.new[0][0]` but I think that's improper syntax. If I initialize the array at size 3 like this, is it possible to push another row? Or even initialize an empty 2D array and add rows as I go along?

Comment: Sure, just do `list << []` or `list.push([])` to add another array.

Comment: I've edited your question to provide an actual example. Hope I got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize an nested array of size 3 via:

```
list = [[], [], []]
```

or via:

```
list = Array.new(3) { [] }
```

To push to one of the arrays you can use: (`[0]` refers to the array at index `0`)

```
list[0].push(Item.new("foo"))

list
#=> [[#<Item @name="foo">], [], []]
```

To pop it off again:

```
list[0].pop
#=> #<Item @name="foo">

list
#=> [[], [], []]
```

To add another row, you simply push a new array to `list`:

```
list.push([])

# or

list << []
```

---

You might also want to take a look at hashes. A hash with a default value of `[]` can be very versatile:

```
list = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }

list[:foo].push(Item.new("foo"))
list[:foo].push(Item.new("foo"))
list[:bar].push(Item.new("bar"))

list
#=> {
#     :foo=>[
#       #<Item @name="foo">,
#       #<Item @name="foo">
#     ],
#     :bar=>[
#       #<Item @name="bar">
#     ]
#   }

list[:foo].pop
#=> #<Item @name="foo">

list
#=> {
#     :foo=>[
#       #<Item @name="foo">,
#     ],
#     :bar=>[
#       #<Item @name="bar">
#     ]
#   }
```

Comment: The hash is very interesting but every value needs to be unique for a hash right? Would a hash still work if I'm taking in multiple class objects that would be completely indentical?

Comment: @JasonStatham every _key_ needs to be unique in a hash. I’m not sure what you are trying to do. Maybe you can give an actual example?

Comment: @JasonStatham BTW if this answer was helpful, you might want to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it. If it solved your problem, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.